# How to use regex in bash aliases

Tags: regex, bash, alias

I often write `ccclear` instead of `clear`.

Is it possible to use regex in an alias ? Something like :

```
alias c\+lear='clear'
```

Comment: i think, it's not possible..

Comment: @AvinashRaj, ...not with an alias, no. The desired behavior can be achieved in other ways, though.

Comment: Use a keyboard shortcut for `clear`. It is a frequent enough operation. `Ctrl+L` should work with the default settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Aliases run simple prefix substitution, and aren't powerful enough for much else.

However, in Bash 4, you can use a function called `command_not_found_handle` to trigger on this case and run logic of your choice.

```
command_not_found_handle() {
  if [[ $1 =~ ^c+lear$ ]]; then
    clear
  else
    return 127
  fi
}
```

If you happen to be using zsh, the function must be called `command_not_found_handler`.

If you wanted to be able to add new mappings dynamically:

```
declare -A common_typos=()
common_typos['^c+lear$']=clear
command_not_found_handle() {
  local cmd=$1; shift
  for regex in "${!common_typos[@]}"; do
    if [[ $cmd =~ $regex ]]; then
      "${common_typos[$regex]}" "$@"
      return
    fi
  done
  return 127
}
```

With the above, you can add new mappings trivially:

```
common_typos['^ls+$']=ls
```

Comment: Ouch! Had a subtle bug here, where I was iterating through replacements rather than regexes. A corrected version is now in place.

Comment: Just to note, in ZSH the function would have to be called `command_not_found_handler`